# How can I close a child window when its parent window is closed? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a child window that is created and displayed via `Show()`. The user may close the main application window, but my child window is still displayed. How can I handle this situation? My preference would be to handle this all from the child window's constructor, as this window may be instantiated from a number of locations. In other words, I don't want to have to add to the main window's "Closing" event handler, code specifically to close this child window, e.g.:

```
_mainWindow.Closed += (_, __) => _childWindow.Close();
```

This seems like a pretty typical use-case to me so I'm surprised not to find an answer easily. Perhaps I'm approaching this from the wrong angle?

Comment: You can set the [`ShutdownMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Application_ShutdownMode) of your application to `OnMainWindowClose`. The default behaviour is `OnLastWindowClose`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the Windows.Owner property.

```
_childWindow.Owner = _mainWindow;
```

This automatically adds the behaviour of when you close the mainWindow, the childWindow will be closed. However it also comes with other behaviours which you may or may not want. Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=netframework-4.7.2

If you don't want these additional behaviours, you could do basically what you've already done but put it in the childWindows constructor like you want.

```
public childWindow(Window parentWindow)
{
    parentWindow.Closed += (s, e) => this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hm, I like the owner idea but it seems my issue is not having easy access to the parent window. How might I identify and use the parent window from a control? This might be a really simple question...

Comment: @sean Its hard to say without knowing more about how your code is set up. If you're calling from within a UserControl or something try `Window.GetWindow(this)`?

Comment: Going with `Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow` in the child window's constructor. I prefer this owner-ship idea for handling this sort of maintenance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than handling this from the child window, and having to repeat that code for every new child window you might create, why not keep track of when the main window closes from the Application class (in App.xaml.cs), and then also close all child windows? That way, the child window doesn't have to keep any references to the parent window, and you can do it all from the central App class.

Something like

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
}

private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // close all child windows.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hook up an event handler to the application's main window's `Closed` event in the constructor of the child window:

```
public partial class ChildWindow : Window
{
    public ChildWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            mainWindow.Closed += (s, e) => Close();
    }
}
```

Or you can set the `ShutdownMode` of your application to `OnMainWindowClose` in your `App.xaml.cs` class as suggested by @ChristianMurschall:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
    }
}
```