# Close wpf window from another wpf window in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I designed a WPF Window and when I press ESC another small window opens which asks "Are you sure you want to exit?". When I press Yes I want to close the confirmation window and the main window. How can I do that in WPF C#? I used this method.
`Mainwindow mainwin=new Mainwindow();`
`mainwin.Close();`
when the yes button is pressed.

Comment: what is that 'small window', is that a Form that you created? share the relevant code snippets from your project.

Comment: See if the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711736/how-can-i-close-a-child-window-when-its-parent-window-is-closed-wpf), meets your need.

Comment: Its another WPf window

Comment: In the event handler in the confirmation form, you need to have the reference of the main form, so that you can call Close() on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling the window closing event with WPF / MVVM Light Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683450/handling-the-window-closing-event-with-wpf-mvvm-light-toolkit).  Ignore the _" MVVM Light Toolkit"_ aspect

Comment: Please improve your question and post the code that shows how you show the dialog. What exactly is not working when you call `mainwin.Close();`?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the window as a dialog, then when you close it emits a confirmation response and then closes.

```
 Secondview = new Secondview ();

            if (view.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
```